# Align divs on vertical columns

Tags: html, css

I try to reproduce the Github contributions graph (see the following screenshot)

> [image]

Each square has `.day` class. I named the container `.gh-contributions`.

The problem is that I cannot align divs in this way.

```
 1 8
 2 9
 3 10
 4 11
 5 12
 6 ...
 7
```

If I add `float:left` to `.day` I get:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```

If I remove it I get:

```
 1
 2
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 ...
```

My CSS code is:

```
.day {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: white;
    margin: 1px;
}

.gh-contributions {
    width: 775px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 120px;
    background: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 10%;
}
.active {
    background: red !important;
}
```

See the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZKxM/).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap each seven days in a .week class just like this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tZKxM/2/, and set properties like:

```
.week{
    height:120px;
    width: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The html generator (js) is a little bit hard, but made it to work. :-)

Comment: Great! I hope it looks awesome (the idea is great)

Comment: Yes, I will use it [here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/gh-contributions). You can star and fork the project. ;-)